# Supercollider is truncating console output in Post window

Tags: console, supercollider

I am trying to find all devices options for my supercollider setup.

Running `ServerOptions.devices;` ( https://doc.sccode.org/Reference/AudioDeviceSelection.html ) truncates the string that is output in the "Post window". This is the output:

```
[ MME : Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input, MME : Line (Roland Rubix 22), MME : Microphone Array (Realtek High , MME : Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output, MME : Speakers (Realtek High Definiti, MME : Speakers (Roland Rubix 22), Windows DirectSound : Primary Sound Capture Driver, Windows DirectSound : Line (Roland Rubix 22), Windows DirectSound : Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows DirectSound : Primary Sound Driver, Windows DirectSound : Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio), Windows Direc...etc...
```

Is there a way to make the log display the entire content of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an array.  Try:

```
ServerOptions.devices.do({|dev|
  dev.postln;
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! So since it's an array, you are telling it to run a function with arg `dev` and foreach `dev` it will post it in the Post Window

Comment: Also found this now for posts that are too long: https://thormagnusson.gitbooks.io/scoring/content/PartI/chapter_1.html using `Post << ServerOptions.devices;` also works, but not as nicely as your solution, since it won't post new lines